# Can't fetch custom model from mapview did change state function

Tags: swift

I'm trying to print out my post model when the drag state has finished but for some reason, it won't print out anything. I have attached my model which is workings fine with the `viewFor` function. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {

    if newState == MKAnnotationViewDragState.ending {
        if let annon = view.annotation?.coordinate as? MyAnno {

            print(annon.post?.id) //Not working

            view.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragState.none
        }
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
    guard let annotation = annotation as? MyAnno else {return nil}
    var identifier = ""
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(
        withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        annotationView = dequedView
    } else {
        annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
}
```

**Model:**

```
class MyAnno: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var post: Post?
var title: String?

init(post: Post, title: String?, subtitle: String?, latitude:CLLocationDegrees, longitude:CLLocationDegrees) {
    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    self.title = title
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a `.coordinate` which is not needed

Please change this line:

```
if let annon = view.annotation?.coordinate as? MyAnno {
```

to

```
if let annon = view.annotation as? MyAnno {
```